# ¿Cómo liberar archivo PDF que ya no está en uso por PdfStamper en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf

Quisiera saber como "libero" un archivo que mi programa ya no esta usando (Se supone) pero al tratar de eliminarlo el sistema me dice que mi programa lo tiene abierto, utilizo `PdfStamper` para ponerle el numero de hojas a un documento `pdf` , pero cuando quiero eliminar el original no me deja por esto, les dejo el fragmento de código de como lo estoy usando:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\PDFs\remision.pdf");
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\PDFs\remision2.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
    {
        int PageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 1; i <= PageCount; i++)
        {
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
                stamper.GetOverContent(i), 
                Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 
                new Phrase(String.Format("{0} de {1}", i, PageCount)), 
                550, 25, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Quiero eliminar el archivo "remision.pdf" pero no me deja aunque si quiero eliminar el archivo resultante de contar las hojas ("remision2.pdf") si me deja, pero el archivo original solo puedo eliminarlo hasta que cierro todo el programa y no puedo estar cerrando el programa cada que uso esta función.

Comment: El problema está probablemente en que la instancia de `PdfReader` no se libera realmente hasta que finalizas el programa. ¿Esta clase implementa `IDisponsable`?

Comment: @jachguate, no pero por tu comentario se me ocurrio cerrar el reader con  reader.Close(); y el problema se soluciono, muchas gracias, ahora agrego la edicion con la respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema se da debido a que nunca cierras el archivo, para hacerlo, podes usar el método `Close()` de la clase `PdfReader`

```
PdfReader reader = default(PdfReader);    
try{
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\PDFs\remision2.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\PDFs\remision.pdf");
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
            {
                int PageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int i = 1; i <= PageCount; i++)
                {
                    ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.Format("{0} de {1}", i, PageCount)), 550, 25, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
catch{ /* Manejas la posible excepción */ }
//Finally para asegurarnos que el documento se cierre.
finally
{
    //Agrego el ? por si se da el caso de que reader sea null.
    reader?.Close();
}
```

De esta manera el archivo debería liberarse.

Comment: Justo por un comentario arriba me di cuenta de eso y si, con el reader.Close(); se soluciono

Comment: Lo que yo haría es meter esto dentro de una estructura `try`/`finally`, para asegurarme que la llamada a `Close` se ejecute independientemente de si hay algún error en tiempo de ejecución. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate me parece una buena adición, ahora edito la respuesta, gracias!

Comment: He visto la edición, apunto un par de cosas. 1. No hace falta sugerir un `catch`, de hecho, es algo perverso hacerlo. Generalmente el `try`/`finally` son suficientes. 2. No hace falta el `?`, dado que la asignación viene con la creación del objeto justo antes del `try`, dentro del `finally` siempre va a estar asignado. Si fallara la construcción del objeto, se lanza un error en el constructor, la variable no se asigna y nunca se ejecuta el `try`/`finally`, pues sale con estado de excepción.